# Devolver objetos entre dos fechas dadas C#

Tags: c#, datetime

estaba intentando que al recibir dos fechas me devuelva los objetos de las compras hechas entre esas dos fechas. Claramente sé que está mal el fecha1 < fecha 2 pero estuve buscando y ya ando bastante rendida al respecto, la cosa sería usar algo sencillo porque no estoy dando c# en profundidad.

De las propiedades de DateTime puedo usar AddDays, CompareTo, Substract.

```
public List<Compra> ComprasFechas(DateTime fecha1, DateTime fecha2)
        {
            List<Compra> aux = new List<Compra>();
            foreach(Compra c in compras)
            {
                if(fecha1 < fecha2)
                {
                    aux.Add(c);
                }

            }
            return aux;
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que es compra? supongo que compra tiene una fecha no? esa fecha.. entre que fechas deberia estar?

Comment: No estás comparando la fecha de cada compra. Debes hacer algo como `if (c.Fecha > fecha1 && c.Fecha< fecha2)...`

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir la definición del objeto `Compra`?

Answer (score 0):

**Suponiendo** que tu objeto `Compra` tiene algún elemento que identifica la fecha de la compra, bastará con modificar tu condición del `foreach`:

```
foreach(Compra c in compras)
{
   if(c.fechaDeCompra >fecha1 && c.fechaDeCompra<fecha2)
   {
      aux.Add(c);
   }
}
```